# How to execute "Sync Project with Gradle Files" using Command line for a project?

Tags: java, android, gradle, command-line

I want to sync my project with its dependencies using Windows Command Line. Is there any way to do this? I have read a few posts about this problem but none of theme worked. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sync Project with Gradle Files" is only Android Studio's problem. Android Studio needs to take a look at your project and cache some values. It has nothing to do with the actual build, which can be invoked standalone from the command line.

When you open the project in Android Studio or when you make any changes to the build script in text editor while the project is opened, you will have to re-sync, so the dialogs, such as Project Structure dialog, show the correct values.

There's no reason and no way to "Sync [Android Studio] Project with Gradle Files" from command line, and that's fine. Android Studio does it when needed, or tells you to do it, and nobody else besides Android Studio cares.